# Raw sequelize Queries work on aws but findAll method doesn't work

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, sequelize.js

I'm using lambda to launch SQL query with node, I've tried with raw queries and it works but when I test it with the findAll method from sequelize the code doesn't enter in the "then close" I don't understand why.

Heere the code that doesn't work

```
    models.lb2b
    .findAll({
      order: [["id", "DESC"]],
      attributes: [
        "id",
        "version",

      ],
    })
    .then((lb2b) => {
      return  {
        statusCode : 200, 
        body : JSON.stringify(
          {
            message : lb2b 
          }
        )
      }
    });

    return response
};
```

here the code that work

```
  const lb2b = await sequelize.query("SELECT * FROM lb2b", 
  {
    type : QueryTypes.SELECT
  }
  ); 
  return {
    statusCode : 200, 
    body : JSON.stringify(
      {
        message : lb2b 
      }
    )
  }
```

Comment: maybe you should add some error handling (ie a `.catch(error => {...})`)  to your code and check what error is thrown ...

Comment: Ok let's try it :)

Answer (score 0):

`return` in `then` only returns a value from `then` and does not finish the outer function, it's better to use `await` instead of `then` just like you did with the raw query.

```js
const lb2b = await models.lb2b
    .findAll({
      order: [["id", "DESC"]],
      attributes: [
        "id",
        "version",

      ],
    });

return {
  statusCode : 200, 
  body : JSON.stringify(
  {
    message : lb2b 
  }
};
```